# Python program which returns the properties of a number by choosing a random number in a given range?

Tags: python, list, loops

I want to create a function in which system takes a random number from the given range and tell us about it's properties like odd-even number, prime-composite number, positive-negative number. It would be good if it's in Python3

I have although created function but somehow its showing some errors during compiling

```
import random
A = eval(input("Enter the Range from: "))
B = eval(input("Enter the Range to: "))

num = random.randint(A,B)
if num>=1:
    print(num,"is positive number")
    if num%2==0:
         print(num,"is even number")
    else:
        print(num,"is odd number")
    if num >= 1:
        for i in range(2,num+1):
            if num%2i==0:
                print(num,"is a composite number")
                break
        else:
            print(num,"is a prime number")
    elif num==0 or num==1:
        print(num,"is neither prime nor composite")
    else:
        print(num,"is a prime number")
elif num==0:
    print(num,"is neither positive nor negative")
    print(num,"is neither even nor odd")
    print(num,"is neither prime nor composite")
else:
    print(num,"is negative number")
```

Comment: Very bad idea to `eval` arbitrary user input. What error do you get?

Comment: Python is not compiled. Errors are only detected at run-time. But what are those "some errors" ?

Comment: `int(input()).. ` will be nice option..

Comment: `if num%2i==0:` ???

Comment: @YvesDaoust All current Python implementations compile Python code to something and detect syntax errors in the process.  You found the same one that compile() does, and the only one.

Comment: Hitest: the compiler clearly identified `2i` as an error.  You should have fixed that yourself by removing the `i`.  Syntax errors, especially if typos, are not legitimate questions.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy: Idle does not. And that still does not make Python a compiled language.

Comment: @YvesDaoust IDLE first executes `codeobject = compile(user_code)`.  That is when SyntaxErrors are raised and reported.  IDLE then calls `exec(codeobject)`, usually in a separate process.  That is when runtime errors occur.  Quibbling about this does not help users, especially new users.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy; this occurs when you execute, not before. That still does not make Python a compiled language. Bad idea to support this.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
import random

A = int(input("Enter the Range from: "))
B = int(input("Enter the Range to: "))

def number_properties(start, end):
  # Generate a random number from the given range
  number = random.randint(start, end)
  
  # Check if the number is odd or even
  if number % 2 == 0:
    odd_even = "even"
  else:
    odd_even = "odd"
  
  # Check if the number is prime or composite
  if number < 2:
    prime_composite = "neither prime nor composite"
  elif number == 2:
    prime_composite = "prime"
  else:
    for i in range(2, number):
      if number % i == 0:
        prime_composite = "composite"
        break
    else:
      prime_composite = "prime"
  
  # Check if the number is positive or negative
  if number < 0:
    positive_negative = "negative"
  elif number == 0:
    positive_negative = "neither positive nor negative"
  else:
    positive_negative = "positive"
  
  # Print the properties of the number
  print(f"The number {number} is {odd_even}, {prime_composite}, and {positive_negative}.")

number_properties(A, B)
```